# Does deleting an answer affect the attached reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, deletion

I have recently seen  some  answers deleted by the users who had posted them. Do these users keep the reputation points (positive or negative) acquired by these answers just before deletion?

[And is the answer for MathOverflow the same? I'm asking here, so that with some luck I won't have to post the same question there.]

Comment: [Sure, the rep gain/loss is canceled, but not until a rep recalc is triggered.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308)

Comment: Thank you, J.M. Do you happen to know if it is the same on MO?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, sorry. I don't know if what applies in the current version of the SE engine was also in SE 1.0 ...

Comment: No problem, thanks again J.M.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation is currently denormalized.

Thus, if an answer is deleted, the reputation will *eventually* be removed from the user, but only at the time when that user's reputation is recalculated.

This happens.. irregularly, but can be triggered manually.